# Search phone number from MYSQL DB

Tags: mysql, regex

I have a table with `phone` column. Phones in it looks like this +1 (123) 456-3780.
If user input in search field "35" i should show him all users with phones:

```
+3 (534) 000-1010

+1 (350) 000-9090

+1 (003) 534-2343

+1 (001) 223-5323 etc.
```

i have tried to do something like that

```
SELECT * FROM `mytable` WHERE `phone` LIKE '%3%5'
```

but this is not the best solution, beacause query get other phones like that +3 (000) 000-500.

I would like to use RLIKE or something like that, but do not know how create needed regular expression and how should it look?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a `[() -]*` between each input character:

```
SELECT * FROM `mytable`
WHERE `phone` REGEXP '3[() -]*5'
```

This allows punctuation to exist inside your digit "string" but nothing else.

Comment: Or just a non-digit class, since the input is free-form.

Comment: Any input with different punctuation would be invalid (whether it's actually validated in the OP's code or not) and as such I would expect all lookups on it to fail.

Answer (score -1):

`REGEXP '^(.{2})+(\.{4}[-].{4})$'` this pattern is for phone numbers with ()

example: `(00)0000-0000`